# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on the top level import Vue from 'vue';

Tags: vue.js

I am beginner in Vue and i am facing this error on the chrome browser.
At runtime i see this error.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on the top level

I use the latest version of vue, vue-cli and npm.

Comment: You have to run using `npm run dev`, are you?

Comment: Same issue... Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by ***not*** including the dev `app.js` `(resources/assets/js/app.js)`, try include the compiled `app.js` `(public/js/app.js)` right after you `"npm run dev"`.
The browser will not recognize it as it was still in es6 coding... so compiling it and using the compiled js should fix your issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using typescript with vue.

Include the following `vue-shims.d.ts` file in the root of your Project folder. Its necessary so that typescript doesnt throw errors when importing.vue files.

```
declare module "*.vue" {
   import Vue from "vue";
   export default Vue;
}
```

See Tutorial link: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter

Solution: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter/blob/master/src/vue-shims.d.ts